# How to use @FXML in javafx?

Tags: javafx, annotations, fxml

Trying to connect the 'fxml' and the Label but,
Here '@FXML' annotation is disallowed and the Label object 'myMessage' is saying that the 'private' identifier is not allowed only 'final' is allowed.
I am not getting. A little help here guys...thanks.

```
 public class MainController {
    public void RandomMethod(ActionEvent event){
        @FXML
    private Label myMessage;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = rand.nextInt(50)+1;
    myMessage.setText(Integer.toString(num));
 }
```

Comment: Field declarations are not allowed inside methods.

Comment: Your `myMessage` is a _local variable_ (i.e. in the scope of a method). Not only are those not allowed to have modifiers such as `private`, but the [`@FXML`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXML.html) annotation can only be placed on _fields_ and methods.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Fix your code, provide complete but minimal example and post all error messages.

Comment: @Frieder It pretty much seems to be complete... At least there is enough info to identify the problem and at least the gist of the error message is posted.

Comment: Code has wrong intendation and is missing at least one curly braces, so it is not complete. We don't know what the problem is, c&p error or real code?

Comment: Tank you for responding.....i got it..

Answer (score 1):

There are few mistakes in your code

1. The closing bracket for the function RandomMethod is missing.
2. Don't declare **Label myMessage** inside the the function, instead declare it globally.

The correct code should be like this.

```
     public class MainController {
        @FXML private Label myMessage;
        public void RandomMethod(ActionEvent event){   
           Random rand = new Random();
           int num = rand.nextInt(50)+1;
           myMessage.setText(Integer.toString(num));
        }
     }
```